# show google map in flex, actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, google-maps

I want to show the google map of my company in the company website. I read on the google maps site that new keys for google map for actionscript are no longer available. How can I show google map in the site?

Comment: Looks like no new flash apps with google maps. how about yahoo maps api ?

Answer (score 1):

These are the two alternatives you have :

[Bing Maps Platform in Flash/Flex/ActionScript](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2009/11/30/bing-maps-platform-in-flash-flex-actionscript.aspx)

[Yahoo! Maps AS-Flash API](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/flash/asGettingStarted.html)

Comment: I will give a try to both of the above ways.

Comment: Just note that Yahoo! Maps was shut down last year (September 13, 2011) http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/

Answer (score 1):

[MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com) offers both [Flash](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash) and [Mobile Flash APIs](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash-mobile) and they ARE supported!
Obviously this isn't a solution that involves Google, but I've been happy with the MapQuest Flash APIs.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

These are the alternatives we've been deciding between:

Flex Only

1. ESRI ArcGIS Flex API

AS3

1. [OpenScales](http://openscales.org/)
2. [ModestMaps](http://modestmaps.com/)
3. [MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash)

As a side note if you are just trying to show a simple map on your website, perhaps you should consider the JS Google Maps API? It's fairly simple to add a small map to a html page. Check out http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually I have to use this map in flex. The website I am building is in flex.

Comment: You can use any of the components I listed in flex. I've started using OpenScales as my main alternative to Google maps, it's a very powerful GIS solution.